# PHP Form doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

My contact form doesn't work. Emails are not being sent.

Webpage Code :

```
<!--Form Start-->
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
    Email: <input name="email" type="text"><br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<!--Form End-->
```

PHP Script :

```
<?php
$to = "oxydyzestudios@gmail.com";
$subject = "Comment";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$headers = "From: $email";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($sent) {
    print "Your mail was sent successfully";
} else {
    print "We encountered an error sending your mail";
}
?>
```

Yes, the email is correct.

Live Demo : http://unitedasone.web1337.net/form.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I heard that free hosting providers forbid the use of `mail()` due to people abusing it for spam.

Comment: `My contact form doesn't work.` Way to get downvotes with such opening.

Comment: can you try by replacing `$headers` with `"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()`. Full : `$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()) ; `

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code and it reports success.

This is likely a problem with your mail set up on your server, if you're seeing `Your mail was sent successfully` then php's mail function has successfully passed the mail to the server for delivery.

From php.net:

> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

How is mail sent on your server?